# Conditionally set keyWindow rootViewController from storyboard instantiate not working in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uiapplication

I have a login for my app, so I need to conditionally set the `keyWindow` `rootViewController` based on if they have saved authentication. If there is authentication, show the `tabBarController`, if there isn't, show the login view.

In my `Storyboard` I have sort of a dummy view set as the initial view controller, then in that VC's `viewDidLoad` I have the following logic:

```
if (showTab) {

    UITabBarController *rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ZSSTabBarController"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:rootViewController];

} else {

    ZSSLogin *login = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ZSSLogin"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setRootViewController:login];

}//end
```

I am instantiating the viewControllers from my `Storyboard` which seems easy enough. But, for some reason this does not work in `iOS7`, only `iOS8`. When trying to load the login screen on `iOS7` I just get sort of a blank view, assuming that it is still showing the dummy VC and never replacing that with the login view.

Why would this not work on `iOS7` but work great in `iOS8`? What has changed that made this work in 8?